# Is it possible to use Protractor completely for back-end testing?

Tags: automated-tests, protractor

I've been developing an e2e testing framework using Protractor and Jasmine2 as my core frameworks to build on. In order to extend this beyond UI testing I need to be able to test completely back-end applications. In these situations the browser isn't needed (but will likely pop up). So my question is - can the browser instance be disabled?

(I haven't started developing the back end yet as I'd like to know the answer to this question first...)

Comment: I think it will be much easier to create separate test suite using pure Jasmine to test back-end. What kind of back-end testing would you like to perform? If these are REST API tests, consider using frisby.js

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :) I was afraid that would be the case - I was just hoping to keep everything together and compatible but thanks for the advice.